# Convert convert syntax to PHP (ImageMagick)

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm very new to the whole ImageMagick PHP library. I need to port this function to PHP using ImageMagick:

```
convert staticmap.png -gaussian-blur 10 
    \( -size 300x600 gradient:'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'-'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)' -rotate 270 \) 
    -gravity north -compose over -composite output.png
```

or something that will give this output:

[image: Gradient Map]

I can't use `shell_exec` like I always have because I'm running on Google App Engine and I don't think that function is enabled.

Is there an easier way to get the desired result? I want to blur it, too, but I think I can figure that part out.

**EDIT:** found a better way to do this on the command line. Hopefully that'll help conversion into PHP?

Comment: reformatted command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy as all [CLI options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) map directly to [ImagickMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

```php
<?php
/* convert */
// staticmap.png
$staticMap = new Imagick('staticmap.png');
// -gaussian-blur 10x0
$staticMap->gaussianBlurImage(10, 0);
// -size 300x600 gradient:'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'-'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newPseudoImage(300, 600, 'gradient:rgba(255,255,255,0.9)-rgba(255,255,255,0.1)');
//  -rotate 270
$mask->rotateImage('black', 270);
// -gravity north
$staticMap->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTH);
// -compose over -composite
$staticMap->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
// output.png 
$staticMap->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: Convert convert syntax to PHP]